# Datepicker is not working properly first time

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am facing one problem that Datepicker is not working properly first time, i.e. first time when i open the page and click on "from"/"to" input field, the datepicker opens but I cannot select a date as I get an error on console: "Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker". But when I refresh page, it perfectly works!

Why does this happens?

---

This is my code:

```
$('.datepicker').live('focus',function(){
            $(this).datepicker({
                defaultDate : "+1w",
                changeMonth : true,
                numberOfMonth : 1,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            });
        });
```

can you tell is it right to use '.live' method here?

Comment: You should post some code to let others know what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are doing this

```
$("#datepicker").click(function(){
$(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
});
```

May be only this will work as it did for me

```
$(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
});
```

If its for multiple inputs just make use of class name instead of id.

Comment: you can ignore dateFormat if not needed

Answer (score 0):

for it to show first time you can do this inside on click:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker( "show" )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker').on('focus',function(){
        $(this).datepicker({
            defaultDate : "+1w",
            changeMonth : true,
            numberOfMonth : 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});​
```